# Cannot save more than one user to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I am using nodeJS with the expressJS server framework. This issue is regarding passportJS not saving more than 1 user to MongoDB.

Firstly, I set up email registration with passport-local and got that to work fine. Secondly, I set up passport-facebook which essentially broke my email registration somehow. Each registration (email & facebook) now only log in just 1 user, I have to keep deleting the user from mongodb to register again. When there is 1 user in the database and I try to register another - I receive the error below.

```
process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null    at model.mongodbErrorHandler (/Users/tlr/Dropbox/Websites/app-one/node_modules/mongoose-mongodb-errors/lib/plugin.js:19:49)
at next (/Users/tlr/Dropbox/Websites/app-one/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:145:14)
at Kareem.execPost (/Users/tlr/Dropbox/Websites/app-one/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:193:3)
at /Users/tlr/Dropbox/Websites/app-one/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:219:35
at /Users/tlr/Dropbox/Websites/app-one/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:152:9
at /Users/tlr/Dropbox/Websites/app-one/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:524:20
at /Users/tlr/Dropbox/Websites/app-one/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:658:14
at handleCallback (/Users/tlr/Dropbox/Websites/app-one/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:95:56)
at /Users/tlr/Dropbox/Websites/app-one/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js:465:9
at handleCallback (/Users/tlr/Dropbox/Websites/app-one/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:95:56)
at resultHandler (/Users/tlr/Dropbox/Websites/app-one/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js:413:5)
at /Users/tlr/Dropbox/Websites/app-one/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:455:18
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

I think the issue may lie around the User Schema because each Strategy saves different user information. Thus, local & facebook may not be marrying up properly in the database which causes an error? Correct me if I'm wrong.

The main files to look at are my userSchema (**User.js**), my routes file (**index.js**) where I include my FB Strategy and module imports, and my controller files (**userController.js, authController.js**) where I export my modules and functions.

**User.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const md5 = require('md5');
const validator = require('validator');
const mongodbErrorHandler = require('mongoose-mongodb-errors');
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Please supply a name',
        trim: true,
    },

    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true,
        trim: true,
        required: 'Please supply an email address',
        validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Invalid Email Address']
    },
    id: String,
    token: String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, { usernameField: 'email' });
userSchema.plugin(mongodbErrorHandler);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const User = mongoose.model('User');
const authIDs = require('../../oauth');
const authController = require('../controllers/authController');
const userController = require('../controllers/userController');
const FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
const router = express.Router();

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: authIDs.facebook.clientID,
        clientSecret: authIDs.facebook.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: authIDs.facebook.callbackURL,
        profileFields: ['id', 'emails', 'name'],
        passReqToCallback : true
    },

    function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        const newUser = new User();
        newUser.id = profile.id;
        newUser.token = accessToken;
        newUser.name = profile.name.givenName;
        newUser.email = profile.emails[0].value;

        process.nextTick( function() {
            User.findOne({id: profile.id}, (err, user) => {
                if (err) {
                    return done(err);
                }
                if (!user) {
                    newUser.save().then( user => {
                        done( null, user );
                    } ).catch( err => {
                        done( err );
                    } );
                } else {
                    return done(null, user);
                }
            });
        });
    }
));

router.get( '/login', userController.loginForm);
router.post( '/login', authController.login);
router.get( '/register', userController.registerForm);
router.post( '/register',
    userController.validateRegister,
    userController.register,
    authController.login
);

router.get('/auth/facebook', authController.fbauth);
router.get('/auth/facebook/callback', authController.fbcallback);

router.get( '/logout', authController.logout);

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**userController.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');
const promisify = require('es6-promisify');

exports.loginForm = (req, res) => {
    res.render('login')
};

exports.registerForm = (req, res) => {
    res.render('register')
};

exports.validateRegister = (req, res, next) => {
    // express validator methods below
    req.sanitizeBody('name');
    req.checkBody('name', 'You must supply a name!').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'That email is not valid!').isEmail();
    req.sanitizeBody('email').normalizeEmail({
        remove_dots: false,
        remove_extension: false,
        gmail_remove_subaddress: false
    });
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password cannot be blank!').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password-confirm', 'Confirmed password cannot be blank!').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password-confirm', 'Oops! Your passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

    const errors = req.validationErrors();

    if (errors) {
        req.flash('error', errors.map(err => err.msg));
        res.render('register', { body: req.body, flashes: req.flash() });
        return;
    }
    next();
};

exports.register = async (req, res, next) => {
    const user = new User({ name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email});
    const register = promisify(User.register, User);
    await register(user, req.body.password);
    next();
};
```

**authController.js**

```
const passport = require('passport');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');

exports.login = passport.authenticate('local', {
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: 'Failed Login!',
    successRedirect: '/',
    successFlash: 'You are now logged in!'
});

exports.fbauth = passport.authenticate('facebook', {scope: ['email']});

exports.fbcallback = passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        failureFlash: 'Failed Login!',
        successRedirect: '/',
        successFlash: 'You are now logged in!'
});

exports.logout = (req, res, next) => {
    req.logout();
    req.flash('success', 'You successfully logged out!');
    res.redirect('/login')
};
```

Any suggestions on a fix would be suuuuuuuuper duuuuuuper highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OH MY GOD after hours of trying, like most problems solved in coding, this one was terribly embarrassing.

Because I'm using the code as mentioned in the question above, you can see I'm implementing both a local email registration as well as a passport-facebook authentication. So... What was causing that confusing error was the following code was like this:

```
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser(), function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser(), function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

instead of simply being like this:

```
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser(), function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser(), function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});
```